# If $x\in 1+p\mathbb{Z}_p$, is $x^n\equiv 1\mod p^{1+\text{ord}_p(n)}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime, and $\mathbb{Z}_p$ the ring of $p$-adic integers. Suppose $x\in 1 + p\mathbb{Z}_p$ (ie, $x\equiv 1\mod p$), then is
$$x^n\equiv 1\mod p^{1+\text{ord}_p(n)}?$$

If not, is there a nontrivial power $c_n$ depending on $n$ such that we are guaranteed that
$$x^n\equiv 1\mod p^{1+c_n}?$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is not correct. You can try some example and verify this.

For the second one. Yes, there is such $c_n$. In fact, we can even find $c_n$ so that $p^{c_n} \mid x^n-1$ but $p^{c_n+1} \nmid x^n-1$. First, denote $\nu_p(a)=b$ if $p^b \mid a, p^{b+1} \nmid a$. Then for $p \ge 3$ we have $$\nu_p(x^n-1)=\nu_p(x-1)+\nu_p(n). \tag{1}$$
This is known as [Lifting The Exponent Lemma](http://services.artofproblemsolving.com/download.php?id=YXR0YWNobWVudHMvYy82LzdjNTI1OGIyMmNjYmZkZGY4MDhhY2ViZTc3MGE1NDRmMzFhMTEzLnBkZg==&rn=TGlmdGluZyBUaGUgRXhwb25lbnQgTGVtbWEgLSBBbWlyIEhvc3NlaW4gUGFydmFyZGkgLSBWZXJzaW9uIDMucGRm). The proof for this can be found in the given link.

From $(1)$, since $x \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ so $\nu_p(x-1)+\nu_p(n) \ge 1+\nu_p(n)$ so you can choose $c_n=\nu_p(n)$.